# Remove all target="_blank" from links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm messing around with jQuery and ran in to a problem I can't seem to solve. I know it's possible with jQuery, but can't find a proper example to work off of. I have a page with a couple regular links with the attribute/value `target="_blank"` added to it.

What's the best approach with jQuery/JavaScript to remove that value from every link on the page?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This should do it with jQuery...

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target');
```

With a modern browser...

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_blank"]'))
  .forEach(link => link.removeAttribute('target'));
```

With an older browser such as earlier IEs...

```
var links = document.links, i, length;

for (i = 0, length = links.length; i < length; i++) {
    links[i].target == '_blank' && links[i].removeAttribute('target');
}
```

Comment: Why bother with the `.slice()`? Since you're using `.forEach()`, just set the context of that method. `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(...`

Comment: @amnotiam I hadn't considered that, but it is indeed a better way to achieve it. Thanks for your comment, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Not a big fan of doing things in comparison expressions, it's clearer to me and likely others to use 2 extra characters and write : `if (links[i].target == '_blank') links[i].removeAttribute('target');` or just set it to '' regardless: `links[i].target = '';`

Comment: @RobG I agree it can be a little difficult to follow, at first. I thought the `removeAttribute()` would be cleaner than setting `target` to an empty string, I know it's empty even if the attribute is missing but I wasn't sure if it'd remove the attribute if I set to empty when it existed already, not that it matters as the result is the same. The *set it regardless* would overwrite `target` attributes which were not `_blank`.

Comment: Not in a month of Sundays would I ever have come up with version 2 - modern browser code. Arcane but neat.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant answer, very well detailed. Thank you very much!