# Remove the HTML <a> target Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I have a plugin which is outputting hyperlinks like this:

```
<div class="slp-directory-listing">
<a href="https://someURL.com" target="store_locator_plus">More Details</a>
</div
```

Is it possible to remove the target attribute?

I have tried

```
$(".slp-directory-listing p a").removeAttr("target");
```

Comment: have you tried $("#slp-directory-listing p a").attr("target", "");

Comment: your `a` tag is not inside a `p` tag, try with `$(".slp-directory-listing a")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all target="\_blank" from links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098898/remove-all-target-blank-from-links)

Answer (score 2):

You do not have any *p* element in the HTML, remove that from the selector.

```js
$(".slp-directory-listing > a").removeAttr("target");
console.log($(".slp-directory-listing > a").attr("target")); // undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slp-directory-listing">
  <a href="https://someURL.com" target="store_locator_plus">More Details</a>
</div>
```

Comment: True. Just checked the output and the shortcodes produce erratic HTML DOM. Also realised I need target on some hyperlinks. So withdrawing.

Answer (score 0):

Just set it to an empty string - effectively removing it:

```
$("#slp-directory-listing a").attr("target", "");
```

You also have an invalid selector - your `a`  is not inside a `p`:

```
$("#slp-directory-listing a").removeAttr("target");
```